# most efficient way find the greatest common factor of 3 numbers?

Tags: python, math

I need to simplify three numbers as much as I can thus I need the greatest common factor for them.

Right now I'm iterating through all the numbers below the the 3 and checking if it is divisible by them but I'm going to be dealing with very large numbers so that is inefficient. Is there a more efficient way to find the GCF?

Comment: [Euclid!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)

Comment: First find the GCF of the first two numbers, and then find the GCF of *that* number and the third number.

Comment: use the concepts of prime

Comment: @Hackaholic: Determining the prime factorization of the numbers takes much more time than computing the greatest common factor using Euclid's algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have something in the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#fractions.gcd)

```
import fractions
fractions.gcd(100, fractions.gcd(10, 20))
10
```

Comment: Note that this is [Euclidean algorithm](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/fractions.py#l18) only and BTW `gcd` works fine with `reduce`: `reduce(gcd, (10, 20, 100))`

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for the slow (but very simple) way to do this:

```
def find_divisors(number):
    divisors = []
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        if number % i == 0:
            divisors.append(i)
    return divisors

def find_greatest_common_divisor(numbers):
    divisors = [set(find_divisors(number)) for number in numbers]
    common_divisors = set.intersection(*divisors)
    greatest_common_divisor = max(common_divisors)
    return greatest_common_divisor

test_1 = [2, 5]
test_2 = [12, 4, 24]
print(test_1, "->", find_greatest_common_divisor(test_1))
print(test_2, "->", find_greatest_common_divisor(test_2))
```

Which prints:

```
[2, 5] -> 1
[12, 4, 24] -> 4
```